# Spring Boot + JPA + WebSecurity - Como gravar Usuario + Perfil?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-jpa

Olá, já faz alguns dias que estou quebrando a cabeça pra conseguir cadastrar um usuário e sua role. As informações devem ser gravadas em entidades diferentes e não consigo fazer esse relacionamento. Consigo apenas persistir o usuario na tabela 'usuario'. Não consigo persistir a informação de perfil na entidade 'perfil'. Gostaria de entender como poderia funcionar esse relaciomento.

**Hibernate Mappings**

**USUARIO MODEL**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="usuario_perfil", joinColumns = 
    @JoinColumn(name="usuario_id", referencedColumnName="id"), inverseJoinColumns = 
        @JoinColumn(name="perfil", referencedColumnName="rolePerfil"))
private List<Perfil> perfil2;
```

**PERFIL MODEL**

```
@Entity
public class Perfil implements GrantedAuthority{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Enumerated
    private RolePerfil rolePerfil;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "perfil2")
    private List<Usuario> usuarios;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return rolePerfil.toString();
    }

    public List<Usuario> getUsuarios() {
        return usuarios;
    }

    public void setUsuarios(List<Usuario> usuarios) {
        this.usuarios = usuarios;
    }

    public RolePerfil getRolePerfil() {
        return rolePerfil;
    }

    public void setRolePerfil(RolePerfil rolePerfil) {
        this.rolePerfil = rolePerfil;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**Thymeleaf**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="perfil2">Perfil</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="perfil2" id="perfil2">
        <option
            th:each="role : ${T(com.Test.model.RolePerfil).values()}"
            th:value="${role}" th:text="${role}">
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Params**

[image]

**USUARIOS CONTROLLER**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/save")
public ModelAndView save(Usuario usuario, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String senha = passwordEncoder.encode(usuario.getSenha());
    String confirmaSenha = passwordEncoder.encode(usuario.getConfirmaSenha());
    usuario.setSenha(senha);
    usuario.setConfirmaSenha(confirmaSenha);

    System.out.println(usuario);

    usuarioRepository.save(usuario);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Operação realizada com sucesso!");

    return edit(usuario.getId());
}
```

**Console**

```
    Usuario [nome=Bruno, login=bruno, senha=$2a$10..., confirmaSenha=$2a$10...,
email=test@test, dataRegistro=2020-02-13T02:50:23.790, status=true, perfil2=null]
    Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
    Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
    Hibernate: insert into usuario (data_registro, email, login, nome, senha, status, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**Hibernate**

```
Hibernate: create table cliente (id bigint not null, bairro varchar(255), celular varchar(255), cep varchar(255), cidade varchar(255), cpf varchar(255), data_cadastro datetime, data_nascimento date, email varchar(255), endereco varchar(255), estado varchar(255), facebook varchar(255), instagram varchar(255), nome varchar(255), observacoes varchar(255), profissao varchar(255), sexo varchar(255), telefone varchar(255), tipo_pessoa varchar(255), twitter varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: create table perfil (role_perfil integer not null, primary key (role_perfil)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table produto (id bigint not null, altura integer, categoria varchar(255), codigo_barra bigint, comissao decimal(19,2), comprimento integer, custo_operacional decimal(19,2), data_fabricacao datetime, data_validade datetime, descricao varchar(255), estoque integer, estoque_minimo integer, fabricante varchar(255), fornecedor varchar(255), icms decimal(19,2), largura integer, margem_lucro decimal(19,2), modelo varchar(255), nome varchar(255), origem varchar(255), peso integer, preco_promocional decimal(19,2), preco_unidade decimal(19,2), preco_venda decimal(19,2), referencia bigint, unidade varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table usuario (id bigint not null, data_registro datetime, email varchar(255), login varchar(255), nome varchar(255), senha varchar(255), status bit, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table usuario_perfil (usuario_id bigint not null, perfil integer not null) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table usuario_perfil add constraint FKh5di2ijgv1c31x7q4k2xggiga foreign key (perfil) references perfil (role_perfil)
Hibernate: alter table usuario_perfil add constraint FKnrjqnbylalt4ykxbcef24f57w foreign key (usuario_id) references usuario (id)
```

Desde já, muito obrigado senhores.

Comment: Pq Usuário está como `@Id`?

Comment: então gustavo,posso estar enganado, mas acredito que posso deixar o usuario como chave primaria, ja que não vou fazer uso do identificador.

Answer (score 1):

Adicione a associação entre as tabelas.

**CLASSE PERFIL**

```
@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id")
private Usuario usuario;
```

**CLASSE USUÁRIO**

```
@Id
private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "usuario")
private List<Perfil> perfil = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Mesmo com esses mapeamentos nada acontece na tabela Perfil. é preciso persistir o perfilRepository.save(usuario) ou algo do tipo?

Comment: acredito que se eu mapear corretamente as entidades o hibernate faz essa persistência automaticamente. mas está tenso. :(

Comment: Sim, ele faz a persistência do perfil automaticamente quando vc salva o usuário. Olhando o seu controller ali, vc não define nenhum perfil para o usuário. Cria um perfil de teste e adiciona ele à sua lista de perfis do usuário. Ai vc faz a persistência do usuário. Tem o código no git?